# angular *ngFor bootstrap columns last one overflowing to next column

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, multiple-columns, angular7

[image: 3 columns ngFor]

I have varying sized content to `ngFor` loop over and populate a responsive 3 column (content needs to flow down rather than over) modal-body. The last item in the first and the second columns are getting cutoff and flowing to the start of the next column. How can I keep the contents of each grouping together? Is there a way to check if the contents of this will not fit at the bottom of this column, then move the whole thing up to the next?
This is responsive in that as the width shrinks, it will transition to 2 columns and then to 1 column, so it needs to stay dynamically populated with the loop.

**Code:**

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="m-4">
    <div class="columns">
        <div class="green" *ngFor="let cat of categories;let index = index;">
          <div class="row no-gutters justify-content-left text-left">
            <span class="cat-title">title {{index}}</span>
            <span class="cat-subtitle" *ngIf="cat.subtitle">&nbsp;subtitle</span>
          </div>
          <div class="row no-gutters justify-content-left text-left nom-name" *ngIf="cat.iPicked">
            <span>winner picked</span>
          </div>                
          <hr/>              
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> <!-- end modal body -->
```

**CSS:**

```
.ballot-body {
height: 600px;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: map-get($grid-breakpoints, xs)) {
#title {
    font-size: medium;
}
.columns {
    columns: 1;
}
```

-- columns grow to 2 then 3 as the breakpoints grow

Answer (score 1):

You can use **CSS GRID** to solve the problem, `.columns` class should have a `display: grid;` property.

```css
.columns {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 30px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  
}

.features-1, .features-2, .features-3  {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="columns">
  <div class="features-1">
      Feature 1
  </div>
  <div class="features-2">
    Feature 2
  </div>
  <div class="features-3">
    Feature 3
  </div>
  <div class="features-3">
    Feature 3
  </div>
  <div class="features-3">
    Feature 3
  </div>
  <div class="features-3">
    Feature 3
  </div>
  <div class="features-3">
    Feature 3
  </div>
  <div class="features-3">
    Feature 3
  </div>
  <div class="features-3">
    Feature 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After attempting the suggested approach, I was still having issues with the layout. Thanks for the suggestion though! It was informative as it led me to look into what css grid options exist.

In the end, because my content has unknown varying heights and it needed to be responsive (3 cols, 2 cols, 1 col), I opted to do a regular *ngFor over my list, after it has been re-indexed based on the size of the window. Now, each individual grouping stays together as it loops.

```
 ------- parent component --------
// when screen is resized, control how the categoryArray is sorted (1, 2, 3 columns)
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
onresize() {
  this.changeCategoryArray(window.innerWidth);
}

changeCategoryArray(innerWidth) {
    let arrayToUse = [];

    if (innerWidth >= 992) {
      if (this.currentNumberOfColumns !== 3) {
        this.currentNumberOfColumns = 3;
        arrayToUse = this.threeColArray;
      }
    } else if (innerWidth < 992 && innerWidth >= 576) {
       if (this.currentNumberOfColumns !== 2) {
        this.currentNumberOfColumns = 2;
        arrayToUse = this.twoColArray;
       }
    } else if (innerWidth < 575) {
       if (this.currentNumberOfColumns !== 1) {
        this.currentNumberOfColumns = 1;
        arrayToUse = this.oneColArray;
       }
    }
    // only change it if it is not already set to the this number of columns
    if (arrayToUse.length) {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.categories.length; i++) {
        this.newCategoryArray[arrayToUse[i]] = this.categories[i];
      }
    }
}

------------html----------
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row m-4">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4" *ngFor="let item of newCategoryArray">
            <ballot-category [categoryItem]="item"></ballot-category>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- end modal body -->

-----<ballet-category>------
<div class="pl-4 pr-4">
   <div class="justify-content-sm-start justify-content-center text-sm-left text-center">
     <span class="cat-title" [ngClass]="{'title-notPicked': !categoryItem.iPicked}">{{categoryItem.name}}</span>
     <span class="cat-subtitle" *ngIf="categoryItem.subtitle" [ngClass]="{'title-notPicked': !categoryItem.iPicked}">&nbsp;{{categoryItem.subtitle}}</span>
   </div>
   <div class="justify-content-sm-start justify-content-center text-sm-left text-center nom-name" *ngIf="categoryItem.iPicked">
     <span>{{categoryItem.nomPicked}}</span>
   </div>
   <div class="justify-content-sm-start justify-content-center text-sm-left text-center nom-name-notPicked" *ngIf="!categoryItem.iPicked">
     <span>/// Not chosen yet ///</span>
   </div>
   <hr />
</div>
```